# Netbeans Maven project from cloned GitHub Java (with jni and C) repository

Tags: java, git, maven, netbeans, github

I cloned the git repository [here](https://github.com/s-u/rJava) and I would like to add it as a `Maven` or `NetBeans` `Java` project in `NetBeans`so I can use it as dependency for other application and to also be able to contribute to the repository.

The problem is that after cloning it `NetBeans` does not allow me to add it as a project. I'm guessing this is because it does not follow the structure of neither Maven, nor Netbeans projects.

Is there any way I can add it as a project in `NetBeans` and still have it liked to the `GitHub` repository so I can commit and push changes?
The project is using `Java`, jni with `C` and `R` (I think).

Comment: That's not a Maven project...

Comment: I know. Any way I can import it into one? Or at least a Netbeans project. I know I can create a new project and then start copy pasting the sources into it, but I will lose the link to the GitHub repository (or so I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Anubian Noob's  answer I tried the same for Maven and the following will get you a Maven project:

1. Create a new Java Maven project: NetBeans -> New Project -> Maven -> Java Application
2. Open up your terminal and navigate to the project's directory, then to src/main/java/ inside the project
3. Run `git clone https://github.com/s-u/rJava.git --recursive`

Anubian Noob's commands also work for initializing the git repository inside src/main/java folder but I couldn't get the submodules.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new project and then pull into it.

1. Create a new Netbeans Java project.
2. Open up your terminal and navigate to that directory.
3. Initialize a git repo: `git init`
4. Set the remote: `git remote add origin https://github.com/s-u/rJava.git`
5. Pull: `git pull origin master`

Now you have the project set up!

Comment: great, that did the trick for NetBeans project! many thanks. too bad it does not work for Maven also.

Comment: If it's a Maven project, then there will be a `pom.xml` file in the repo. You can just clone the repo and open it as a Maven project.

Comment: I can confirm it also works with Maven if you create a new Maven project and then initialize the git repo in the /src/main/java folder of your project.

Comment: @Burdu Answer your own question with that then!